# connection timed out; no servers could be reached when connect CoreDNS server

Tags: kubernetes

When I using dig command to test the CoreDNS server,it shows: `connection timed out; no servers could be reached`:

```
[root@ops001 ~]# /opt/k8s/bin/kubectl exec -ti soa-user-service-5c8b744d6d-7p9hr -n dabai-fat /bin/sh
/ # dig -t A kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. @10.254.0.2

; <<>> DiG 9.12.4-P2 <<>> -t A kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. @10.254.0.2
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

when I ping server,it success.

```
[root@ops001 ~]# /opt/k8s/bin/kubectl exec -ti soa-user-service-5c8b744d6d-7p9hr -n dabai-fat /bin/sh
/ # ping 10.254.0.2
PING 10.254.0.2 (10.254.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.254.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.100 ms
64 bytes from 10.254.0.2: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.071 ms
64 bytes from 10.254.0.2: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.094 ms
64 bytes from 10.254.0.2: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.087 ms
```

why the dig could not connect to DNS server althrough the network is ok?This is my CoreDNS service:

[image]

when azshara-k8s03‘s node connection to CoreDNS server:

```
/ # telnet 10.254.0.2 53
Connection closed by foreign host
```

when azshara-k8s02‘s and azshara-k8s01‘s node connection to CoreDNS server:

```
/ # telnet 10.254.0.2 53
telnet: can't connect to remote host (10.254.0.2): Connection refused
```

I just confusing why port 53 is not open,when I scan from host using same command,the port 53 is open:

[image]

Comment: A side note: you're performing `dig` from inside some container and `ping` from the host machine. And a second note: are you sure coredns service is at `10.254.0.2`?

Comment: yes,I am sure CoreDNS at 10.254.0.2

Comment: `kube-dns` is not coredns

Comment: kube-dns just it's name,it actually a coredns.@zerkms

Comment: ok, is it possible to telnet to it from the host machine: `telnet 10.254.0.2 53`?

Comment: I am using telnet to probe 53 port,it give me tips connection refused,I will try more nodes to see where is going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally find some server's kube-proxy not start,and the route foward rule not refresh,using this command to start kube-proxy fix this problem:

```
systemctl start kube-proxy
```